# spin.js spinner not showing

Tags: javascript, spinner, spin.js

I use spin in a webapplication and it works just fine, but in one case, it doesn't.

Before I make an ajax call, i call the function showLoading();

```
function showLoading() {


    $('<div id="divSpin"></div>').appendTo(document.body);

    var target = document.getElementById("divSpin");

    var opts = {
        lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
        length: 20, // The length of each line
        width: 10, // The line thickness
        radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
        corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
        rotate: 8, // The rotation offset
        direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
        color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
        speed: 1, // Rounds per second
        trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
        shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
        hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
        className: 'mySpin', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
        zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
        top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
        left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
    };
    if (mySpinner) mySpinner.spin(target);
    else {
        mySpinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
    }
}
```

in the success function i call the method removeLoading:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: async
    }).success(function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
        callback(data);
        removeLoading();
    });
```

in the removeLoading I only call mySpinner.stop();

The spinner is never shown. The ajax call needs some time to be finished (a few seconds) and if I debug with chrome and make a breakpoint, I see the spin is created, even if I set the breakpoint directly in my removeLoading-function the spin is shown.

thx in advance

©a-x-i

Comment: Create a jsFiddle with the problem. I have a feeling you will resolve it yourself while creating.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can improve a few things first:

1. Your function `showLoading` defines the options, creates an element on-the-fly, appends it to the body and eventually starts the spinner. I would separate this into two steps:

   1.1. Create a function `setupLoading` that creates the element, defines the options and sets `mySpinner`. This function will be called just once, at the beggining.

   1.2. Change `showLoading` to just `mySpinner.spin();`
2. You don't show the call to `showLoading()` so I'm unsure how are you calling the spinner. However, you could use the events `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` to bind automatically (thus removing `removeLoading();` on `.success(..`).

So, here's your code with this changes (and here's [**a working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/2y3p7xoz/)):

```
var mySpinner = null;

function setupLoading() {    
    $('<div id="divSpin" />').appendTo(document.body);

    var target = document.getElementById("divSpin");

    var opts = {
        lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
        length: 20, // The length of each line
        width: 10, // The line thickness
        radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
        corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
        rotate: 8, // The rotation offset
        direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
        color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
        speed: 1, // Rounds per second
        trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
        shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
        hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
        className: 'mySpin', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
        zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
        top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
        left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
    };

    mySpinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
}

function removeLoading(){
    mySpinner.stop();
}

function showLoading() {
    mySpinner.spin();
}

//Setup spinner
setupLoading();

// bind ajax to events
$(document).on('ajaxStart', showLoading);
$(document).on('ajaxStop', removeLoading);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: async
}).success(function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    callback(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It show me partly a different way to solve this problem.
After hours (really!) of trying and coding I found something out.
I changed the code as: now no spinner is added or removed but a DOM-element is toggled. 
And something strange happens, because it seems that nothing happens during the ajax-call. The DOM-element is never hidden, but if the ajax-call takes a few seconds I can see in developer tools that DOM-manipulation is done.
I put the whole ajax-call in a setTimeout and everything works fine.
Something in my code must prevent DOM-Manipulation.
thx again
©a-x-i

Comment: I had the same issue, it's not your code. Also had to put Spinner on setTimeout before a canvas manipulation.